# For each loop on Pandas, each category

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a question.

I have a table like this

```
TAC | Latitude | Longitude
1 | 50.4 | -1.5
```

In Pandas, I wanted to say:

For each TAC, give me a zipped list of latitude and longitude (each TAC can have many rows).

I've tried things like the below, but I am doing something wrong! Can you help?

```
df1['coordinates'] = list(zip(df1.Lat, df1.Long))
new_df = df1.iloc[ : , : ].groupby('TAC').agg(df1['coordinates'])
```

For reference, DF1 is created as below

```
df = pd.read_csv('tacs.csv')
df1 = df[['magnet.tac','magnet.latitude', 'magnet.longitude']]
df1.columns = ['TAC','Lat','Long']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add `usecols` parameter for avoid [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) and then use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tacs.csv', usecols=['magnet.tac','magnet.latitude', 'magnet.longitude'])
df1.columns = ['TAC','Lat','Long']

#sample data
print (df1)
   TAC   Lat  Long
0    1  50.4  -1.5
1    1  50.1  -1.4
2    2  50.2  -1.8
3    2  50.9  -1.3

new_df = df1.groupby('TAC').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x.Lat, x.Long))).reset_index(name='coord')
print (new_df)
   TAC                         coord
0    1  [(50.4, -1.5), (50.1, -1.4)]
1    2  [(50.2, -1.8), (50.9, -1.3)]
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tacs.csv')
df1 = df[['magnet.tac','magnet.latitude', 'magnet.longitude']].copy()
df1.columns = ['TAC','Lat','Long']

df1['coordinates'] = list(zip(df1.Lat, df1.Long))
new_df = df1.groupby('TAC')['coordinates'].agg(list).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. IN both cases I get: /Users/keenek1/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @kikee1222 - Problem is in code before, how is created `df1` ?

Comment: @kikee1222 - In you r code need `.copy()` like `df1 = df[['magnet.tac','magnet.latitude', 'magnet.longitude']].copy()`, but better is use `usecols` here

Comment: Awesome thanks that worked. Why did it require.copy()?

Comment: @kikee1222 - Because it modified copy of data, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)